# Custom meter API on Azure

Tags: azure, azure-cloud-services

Is there an easy way to count calls, or specific items within a call in Azure?

If not, is there an easy way to count the amount of data transferred to the cloud service?

Comment: Check out the Azure Management API.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/ee460799.aspx

Comment: Thanks, @BrendanGreen, but I don't see this info there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The data-transfer-In\out for a cloud service will be part of monthly Azure bill. There is an API available for Enterprise Azure customers (https://automaticbillingspec.blob.core.windows.net/spec/UsageDownloadRestfulSampleClient.zip) but not yet for Credit Card (CC) Customers\non-EA. For CC customer the bill is downloadable as CSV from the management portal

Comment: Thanks, Sri. What about calls and service-specific items?

Comment: Azure only maintains Network In/Out Storage Transactions, can you explain what calls mean here and which service specific items you are looking for? Do you mean Cloud Service specific billing?

Comment: Correct. My own counter contingent on data sent to the Cloud Service. Is there an API to implement it or I will have to build it on my own?

Comment: Yes, data transfer in per cloud service (In GB) is available in the monthly bill for EA subscriptions. And there is a programmatic way to fetch this as mentioned in my answer. For Non-EA subscriptions you might have to build a custom solution, since there is no programmatic way to fetch this information.

Comment: Sorry, no. I meant, for example, if I want to charge per word, or per significant word, etc. If I want my own logic, is there some kind of custom meter set there?